# SSAS 2016- Calculated member caused performance issue when is substracted by static number

Tags: performance, ssas, mdx, calculation

I have cube (with about 1M rows on source) and with these metrics:

- **TotalSales** (defined with SUM aggregation, the source column is defined like bigint)
- **Calculated member**

`IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[TotalSales]), NULL, [Measures].[TotalSales] / 90000.00)`

This calculated member above works fine and take about **1 sec**, but, when i want to substract the same SUM aggregation by static number it makes some performance issue (it take about **20 minutes**) it is the calculation below:

```
IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[TotalSales]), NULL, [Measures].[TotalSales] - 0.5)
```

I don't know what caused so big issue in different arithmetic operator (consequently i tested multiplicative operator(*) and it take same time like division operator, and the sum(+) operator take same time like minus operator (-).

Is there some difference between these operator that it can so big performance issues?

Comment: Not sure why, but the **+** and **-** operators deal with NULL in a different way that **\*** and **/**. 
**+ -** will return the static number, the **\* /** will absorve it and return null. 
Are you sure you have Empty Measure TotalSales?

Comment: So i found the solution and it is that i make one calculated member [Measures].[TotalSalesNonEmpty] like this IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[TotalSales]), NULL, [Measures].[TotalSales]) and another calculated member derived from this calculated member TotalSalesMinusHalf like this [Measures].[TotalSalesNonEmpty] - 0.5 and now it works fine for me, in performance it is very fluent